# How to filter an array by key and push the value to another array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, array-filter

**this is my first array**

```
data=  [{
  "id":1111,
  "date":"2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
  "age":23,
   "email":"test@yahoo.com",
   "address":"phill road",
   "salary":1222.00
},

 {
  "id":222,
  "date":"2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
  "age":24,
   "email":"tes22t@yahoo.com",
   "address":"phill2222 road",
   "salary":3344
}
]
```

**second array should look like this**

```
  dataNew=  [1222.00,3344]
```

I need second array that only contain **the salary value** . How can I filter the first array, that if the **keys name** = "salary" , push the value to new array. Searched for so many suggestion, but nothing seems working for me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```js
data = [{
    "id": 1111,
    "date": "2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
    "age": 23,
    "email": "test@yahoo.com",
    "address": "phill road",
    "salary": 1222.00
  },

  {
    "id": 222,
    "date": "2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
    "age": 24,
    "email": "tes22t@yahoo.com",
    "address": "phill2222 road",
    "salary": 3344
  }
]
arr = []
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i]['salary'])
  arr.push(data[i]['salary']);
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
data=  [{
  "id":1111,
  "date":"2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
  "age":23,
   "email":"test@yahoo.com",
   "address":"phill road",
   "salary":1222.00
},
 {
  "id":222,
  "date":"2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
  "age":24,
   "email":"tes22t@yahoo.com",
   "address":"phill2222 road",
   "salary":3344
},
 {
  "id":223,
  "date":"2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
  "age":24,
   "email":"tes22t@yahoo.com",
   "address":"phill2222 road"
}
]

console.log(data.filter(e => e.salary).map(e => e.salary));
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
data=  [{
  "id":1111,
  "date":"2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
  "age":23,
   "email":"test@yahoo.com",
   "address":"phill road",
   "salary":1222.00
},

 {
  "id":222,
  "date":"2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
  "age":24,
   "email":"tes22t@yahoo.com",
   "address":"phill2222 road",
   "salary":3344
}]

data.map(item =>  item.salary)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the array

```js
data.map(item => item.salary)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data=  [{
  "id":1111,
  "date":"2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
  "age":23,
   "email":"test@yahoo.com",
   "address":"phill road",
   "salary":1222.00
},

 {
  "id":222,
  "date":"2020-08-03T08:00:00+00:00",
  "age":24,
   "email":"tes22t@yahoo.com",
   "address":"phill2222 road",
   "salary":3344
}
]
const dataNew=[]
data.map(item=>item.salary?dataNew.push(item.salary):null)
```